# What is the origin of the phrase "Too busy chopping wood to sharpen the axe"

Tags: phrases

I am writing an article and would like to attribute the phrase correctly.

Comment: I don't know, but what a great phrase!

Answer (score 8):

Abraham Lincoln is said to have said ([1](http://www.alincoln-library.com/abraham-lincoln-quotes.shtml), [2](http://lincolnarchives.com/LincolnQuotes.php))

> If I only had an hour to chop down a tree, I would spend the first 45 minutes sharpening my axe.

from which the variation you mention may stem.  The variation is often credited to  [Zig Ziglar](http://www.news-leader.com/article/20120806/BUSINESS04/308060026/Tom-Black-business-sales-research-advice), or sometimes to [Vance Havner](http://www.thewordteaches.com/Quotes.htm), or to [“old saying”](http://www.homeownernet.com/tools/landscaping/sharpen-garden-tools.html).

Answer (score 0):

This phrase may have its roots in the book of Ecclesiastes, which is part of the Hebrew Bible and the Old Testament.

> If the ax is dull
>
> and its edge unsharpened,
>
> more strength is needed,
>
> but skill will bring success.

(*NIV*, Ecclesiastes 10:10)